# A proof regarding finite abelian groups and their orders.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group of order $p^nm$, where $p$ is a prime that does not divide $m$. Given $G=H\times K$, where $H=\{x\in G|x^{p^n}=e\}$ and $K=\{x\in G|x^m=e\}$. We need to prove that $|H|=p^n$.

I read it's proof which says the following :

$|G|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$ , since $H\cap K ={e}$ => $|H\cap K|=1$.

=> $|G|= |H||K|$ => $p^{n}m=|H||K|$ ,

Now, say $p$ divides $|K|$ => there exists an element of order $p$ in $K$ , but we know that $H$ contains all the elements with order $p$ , so , $H\cap K \neq \phi$ , but that's not possible since $H\cap K ={e}$ , so , $p$ doesn't divide $|K|$.

Now , my question is , from the above statement how do we conclude that $|H|=p^{n}$ ?
Could anyone help ?

Comment: Since $p$ does not divide $|K|$, then $|K|\leq m$. This implies that $|K|=m$ for otherwise it would contradict that $|G|=|H||K|$.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $|H|\geq p^n$. Suppose $|H|=p^nr$ where $r|m$ then there exists $a(\neq e) \in G$ s.t $o(a)|r$ and $a^m=e$ then $a \in H \cap K$ contradiction.